# Print numbers that don't appear in folder Python

Tags: python

I have a folder with a list of files named as follows

```
0.csv, 1.csv, 2.csv .... 359.csv
```

How do I extract the numbers that are missing in these file names? Assuming that the list starts with 0 and ends with 359.

The following code snippet reads all the files in the folder.

```
import os,sys
folder = '..Acad/Code'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
       infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
```

The following code snippet displays the missing elements from a list of integers.

```
def missing_numbers(num_list):
      original_list = [x for x in range(num_list[0], num_list[-1] + 1)]
      num_list = set(num_list)
      return (list(num_list ^ set(original_list)))
```

How do I modify the above snippet to read from the output of the previous code? Any idea?

Comment: use regex to remove .csv from infilename. create a list of numbers and check missing no using `num not in filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `infilename` doesn't collect all file names of the folder, because you overwrite it in each loop. Therefore it only shows the last entry. How about this solution, using list comprehensions:

```
#separate the file name from the file name extension for each file in the folder
filenumbers = [x.split(".")[0] for x in os.listdir(folder)]
#compare numbers in expected range with file numbers in folder
missingnumbers = [i for i in range(360) if str(i) not in set(filenumbers)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a `set` of ints you have as follows:

```
my_set = set(int(f.split('.csv')[0]) for f in os.listdir('./') if os.path.isfile(f) and 'csv' in f)
```

Then compare this with these of all ints:

```
missing_ints = set(range(max(my_list))) - my_set
missing_files = [str(i) + '.csv' for i in missing_ints]
```

This will give you the ints which are not in the list of files you have

So if you have `0.csv` `1.csv` and `3.csv` then `my_set` is `{0, 1, 3}`, `max(my_set)` is 3,  `set(range(max(my_list)))` is `{0, 1, 2, 3}` and then the difference `missing_ints = set(range(max(my_list))) - my_set` is `{2}` and therefore `missing_files = ['2.csv']`

If you have a large number of files comparing `set`s will be faster than comparing strings.